# Setting Character encoding for a project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, character-encoding

In a C# application I am building in Visual Studio v15.4.4 in which I download text from a web api, which is UTF8, but it is rendered by my app in ASCII (I think, e.g. text like "&#39"). I have tried to find a setting to fix this, but failed. Any help would be appreciated.

Tried to find a setting...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apply [HttpUtility Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility) for html entities: `[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode` / `HtmlEncode`  (*given example in PowerShell variant of `.NET`*). In any case, switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: I don't think it's a code issue, I just don't know where in VS to set the character encoding, unless that needs to be set in code.